# using struts tag prefix with ajax

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, struts2

I have virtually no idea about how to use AJAX and jQuery, or how it works, but I want to make a simple login webapp using the Struts 2 framework.

I got a login page template off the net which is as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".username").focus(function() {
          $(".user-icon").css("left","-48px");
      });
      $(".username").blur(function() {
          $(".user-icon").css("left","0px");
      });

      $(".password").focus(function() {
          $(".pass-icon").css("left","-48px");
      });
      $(".password").blur(function() {
          $(".pass-icon").css("left","0px");
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="user-icon"></div>
    <div class="pass-icon"></div>

    <form name="login-form" class="login-form" action="" method="post">
      <div class="header">
        <h1>Login Form</h1>
        <span>
          Fill out the form below to login to my super awesome imaginary control panel.
        </span>
      </div>

      <div class="content">
        <input name="username" type="text" class="input username" value="Username" onfocus="this.value=''" />
        <input name="password" type="password" class="input password" value="Password" onfocus="this.value=''" />
      </div>

      <div class="footer">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" class="button" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" class="register" />
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>

  <div class="gradient"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

To use the framework i included the tag-libs directives and renamed the file to a .jsp type, and then changed the `<form>` tag to `<s:form>` and `</s:form>`.

After doing that, it losts the formatting of the template. I downloaded the struts2-jquery plugin jar and tried to use `<sj: form>` but that resulted in a compile error.

How can I use the struts tag without losing the format and design of the template?

Edit:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzjis.jpg

Here you can see what happens when i edit the `<form>` and `</form>` to `<s:form>` and `</s:form>`, and add the tag-lib page directives:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>
```

I also changed the extension to .jsp and edited nothing else.

Comment: Can you please escape the tags embedded in your text so we can see them? You need to use the simple theme, not sure what else because I can't read your JSP because of all the unrelated stuff and massive amount of commenting.

Comment: +1 for massive amount of commenting :D:D

Comment: And you didn't even include the JSP you were trying to debug--why would that be a good idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Struts2 use [Themes to generate the HTML](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/struts-2-themes.html).

For each theme, the same *Struts2 Tag* (like `<s:select/>`) will generate *different* HTML.

The default theme (the one applied when nothing is specified) is the **XHTML Theme**.

With it, the tag

```
<s:select key="personBean.sport" list="sports" />
```

will generate the following HTML:

```
<tr>
  <td class="tdLabel">
    <label for="save_personBean_sport" class="label">Favorite sport:</label>
  </td>
  <td>
    <select name="personBean.sport" id="save_personBean_sport">
      <option value="football">football</option>
      <option value="baseball">baseball</option>
      <option value="basketball" selected="selected">basketball</option>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
```

[Here you can find the list of the four out-of-the-box themes](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/struts-2-themes.html).

If necessary, you could even roll up your own.

Personally i prefer the **Simple theme** , that will generate the least HTML as possible, leaving to you the generation of the HTML around your tag.

To use it in a tag, simply add it like this:

```
<s:select ... theme="simple" />
```

To set it as the default theme for all the JSP in your project, put the following line inside the struts.xml file:

```
<constant name="struts.ui.theme" value="simple" />
```

To add a **CSS class** to a *Struts2 Tag*, always use `cssClass` instead of `class`;

To add an **inline Style** to a *Struts2 Tag*, always use `cssStyle` instead of `style`

---

Now you have everything you need to draw your components exactly as you want: the resultant HTML and CSS are up to you.

Comment: For anyone else running into the same problem, the fix specifically was: "To add a CSS class to a Struts2 Tag, always use cssClass instead of class;

To add an inline Style to a Struts2 Tag, always use cssStyle instead of style" on top of using the simple theme.

Comment: Nice, I've thought that giving you an overview of all the main features would be better than debugging your code, and it worked :)

Comment: @VinayBangaloreNagaraj Like it says in the tag docs, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
<s:form name="login-form"  theme="simple" class="login-for...
```

Comment: http://imgur.com/GKV4b0P,51RmXhP, Here you can see what happens when i edit the <form> and </form> to <s:form> and </s:form>, and add the tag-lib page directive. I edit nothing else. Thanks for the speedy replies btw.

Comment: alignments are not proper?

Comment: alignments are improper, the grey box collapses and the textfields cannot be writted into

Comment: try to use all fields with s: and set theme="simple"

Comment: When i try to change the fields, i get a compile error No tag "input" defined in tag library imported with prefix "s"

Comment: import this <%@taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>

Comment: I have both of these imported: <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%> <%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>. I feel like using the 's' prefix disables all the css and javascript applied to the form. Is struts2 incompatible with ajax/jquery or css?

Comment: sorry i am unable to find the problem

Comment: Thx, i had to use cssClass after setting the theme.